# C++ Function does not take 2 arguments

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, cocos2d-x

I'm following a tutorial on creating a video game using C++. And I've got stuck on this step:

```
spriteBg -> setAnchorPoint(0,0);
```

I've got an error of: Function does not take 2 arguments

But anchor points are usually two digits pair (x,y) or Vec2::ZERO according with the docs, so what it's wrong with this line?

The guy on the tutorial has a red curvy line under the second 0 as well I have that red line under my second zero in setAnchorPoint(0,0), nevertheless he can build the project without errors but I can't due this error of 2 arguments.

He is using Visual Studio 2012 and I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for what it's worth. The Project was generated with Cocos2d.

This is the whole method.

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{


    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto spriteBg = Sprite::create("images/bg.png");
    spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint(0,0);
    spriteBg ->setPosition(0,0);
    addChild(spriteBg , 0);

    return true;
}
```

This is the whole error:

```
error C2660: 'cocos2d::Sprite::setAnchorPoint': function does not take 2 arguments
```

So far the same result with 5 approaches:

```
spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint(0,0);
spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint({0,0});
spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);
spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));
```

This is the tutorial and this particular step is at 18:27. The tutorial is in Spanish but you clearly can see the guy coding and is just a few lines.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7d3ic_lmGw

Greetings.

Comment: Can you post all your code? Also, as a random guess, try `setAnchorPoint({0, 0})`.

Comment: Sure, but the method it's pretty much just this: 

    bool HelloWorld::init()
    {
    if ( !Layer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    
        auto spriteBg = Sprite::create("images/bg.png");
        spriteBg ->setAnchorPoint(0,0);
        spriteBg ->setPosition(0,0);
        addChild(spriteBg, 0);
    
        return true;
    }

Comment: Please link to the tutorial. Someone may be able to spot a difference.

Comment: Same error with 3 approaches:

spriteFondo->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO);
spriteFondo->setAnchorPoint({0,0});
spriteFondo->setAnchorPoint(0,0);

Comment: Sure Spencer. The tutorial is in spanish, but you crearly can see the guy coding and this particular part is at 18:27.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7d3ic_lmGw

Comment: What cocos2d-x version do you use? Can you go into "setAnchorPoint" to see what's inside? (using ctrl). To me it's some problem with VS or imports.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is without the exact error message, but if you say it takes Vec2::ZERO maybe try:

`spriteBg -> setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));`

Comment: Same error with 4 approaches:
spriteBg->setAnchorPoint(Vec2::ZERO); 
spriteBg->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
spriteBg->setAnchorPoint(0,0); spriteBg->setAnchorPoint({0,0});

Comment: Could you copy paste the entire error output please?

Comment: Sure. error C2660: 'cocos2d::Sprite::setAnchorPoint': function does not take 2 arguments

Comment: I'm not familiar with the cocos2d, but according to the [docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d8/de9/group__sprite__nodes.html#ga08f66701f44bc5b990b29f0e7eaf4c74) you need to pass it a point. Maybe try:

spriteBg->setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));

Comment: Same error with this appoach as well, all It seems that all of these ways are two arguments, which It's an anchor point but in an ironical way the error is there because of two arguments in an function that need 2 arguments at least :(

spriteFondo->setAnchorPoint(Point(0,0));

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned in your error :- error C2660: 'cocos2d::Sprite::setAnchorPoint': function does not take 2 arguments

it takes only one argument of 'Vec2' type.
Try spriteBg -> setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));

Answer (score 0):

Jump to the definition of sprite and look at the function definition for setAnchorPoint. Depending on what version of Cocos2D-x you're using I know for a fact that setAnchorPoint takes a Vec2 object.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of setAnchorPoint in cpp should be a Point(Vec2). Of course you will get the error if the parameters are two number.

It is easy to understand the error by checking the declaration of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works completely, try using:

```
sprite->setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));
```